# My PHP script with str_replace dont function

Tags: php, str-replace

i have a problem with my PHP script that look so here is now complet source from my script sorry i am not a php expert i am only mcu coder please help i habe add that code abowe dont functio here is my complete PHP script

$this->afterbuyString .= "&ArtikelEpreis_".($i)."=".urlencode($this->change_decimal((float)$singleProduct['price']));

return str_replace('.', ',', $wert);

Comment: Try number_format(), http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Comment: please can you write here the code what you mean?

Comment: It may be to do with your use of `(float)` - why is that there?

Comment: alos i have now try it with number_format(), after that dont export any value, @Hammerite i dont know why here is float

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you want to replace dot with comma in float variable. Below is solution for the same. Where I have converted float to sting before using a string function.

```
<?php
var_dump(change_decimal(9.95));

function change_decimal($wert) {
    return str_replace('.', ',', (string) $wert);
}
?>
```

Below is the output of the above code on the browser.

```
string(4) "9,95"
```

Comment: hey thanks i have add but nothing i am realy not php expert only mcu coder :( i have add to my first post the complet php script

Comment: ok ok ok i understand you @v2solutions.com now that works :) with string :) why not work it with float?

Comment: The reason is str_replace is a string function and you are passing float input to it.